# How to correctly rotate object using clamping and euler angles?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation

I've a player (a space-ship ;) that can rotate from -x to +x value (so clamped).
So, before apply rtoation i check it:

```
// Got Horizontal Input 
    h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

// In next code line: I want to take CURRENT x rotation , but if i use
// eulerangles.x i got eulerAngle (from 0 to 360) and it not work for my job 
// angleRotX = Player.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x;

angleRotX += h;
angleRotX = Mathf.Clamp(angleRotX, MinEulerAngleRotX, MaxEulerAngleRotX);
// Apply new rotation: 
Player.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(angleRotX, angleRotY, angleRotZ);
```

Can you help me solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: Your approach of storing your own rotation angles seems like it should work. How does the behaviour of this code differ from what you want?

Comment: We also have [past Q &A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+clamp+euler) about [limiting Euler angles in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+limit+euler) — how have you tried applying past answers to solve your problem so far?